# Addressing 'Transform child out of bounds' exception

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exception

I'm going to set the child `GameObject`'s `SetActive` to true when the parent `GameObject` is triggered.

[image]

Like this picture, `BallIndigo1` is the parent `GameoOject` and `x` is the child `GameObject` which is in `SetActive(false)`.

and I wrote code like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        if (col.transform.GetChild(0) != null)
        {
            col.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No child");
        }
    }
}
```

But the result says:

[image]

I don't know why this happened and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this because the GameObject passed to the `OnTriggerEnter2D` function `col.transform` doesn't have a child. You can fix that by checking if `col.transform.childCount > 0` before calling `col.transform.GetChild(0)`.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
    {
        if (col.transform.childCount > 0 && col.transform.GetChild(0) != null)
        {
            col.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No child");
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you are 100% sure that this Object has a child then there is another GameObject that is being detected that doesn't have a child. You must filter this GameObject out by *tag* or *layer* before calling `col.transform.GetChild(0)`. Create a tag named "Ball" set the Objects you want to detect to this tag. Make sure that the this "Ball" object has a child. The code below should check for that tag and should get ride of that error.

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Ball"))
    {
        if (col.gameObject.activeSelf == true)
        {
            if (col.transform.GetChild(0) != null)
            {
                col.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("No child");
            }
        }
    }
}
```